# facebook like : image posting at facebook

Tags: php, facebook-like

I am working  on an real estate applicatoin and using facebook like in that.

Url : [21flats.com](http://21flats.com)

you can see 3 deals at home page. if you will click on the deal name then it will show the detailed page where you will have facebook like. Now the problem is with the facebook liking of deals. every deal is submitting/posting with a random image. I mean when you click facebook  like then it does not post the og:image but sometimes do. You can view source the page. You can click on each of the deals and can see different thing happening.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shamrma -  this is related to your use of OG:type  Only the root of the domain 21flats.com should have the OG:type of website, all other pages should be article or what they represent.  You can read about the proper usage of OG:type here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#types

> Use article for any URL that represents transient content - such as a
>   news article, blog post, photo, video, etc. Do not use website for
>   this purpose. website and blog are designed to represent an entire
>   site, an og:type tag with types website or blog should usually only
>   appear on the root of a domain.

---

EDIT: 11/14/2011 - 10:45am CST.

> **The Open Graph protocol defines four required properties:**

- og:title - The title of your object as it should appear within the
  graph, e.g., "The Rock".
- og:type - The type of your object, e.g., "movie". See the complete
  list of supported types.
- og:image - An image URL which should represent your object within the
  graph. The image must be at least 50px by 50px and have a maximum
  aspect ratio of 3:1. We support PNG, JPEG and GIF formats. You may include multiple
  og:image tags to associate multiple images with your page.
- og:url - The canonical URL of your object that will be used as its
  permanent ID  in the graph, e.g.,
  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/.

Comment: Shawn Thanks for replying. I used og:type=article but still it does not work properly...21flats.com/beta

Comment: did you run the link in the debugger after making changes?  You also are lacking the url for OG:url <meta property="og:url" content="" />

The debugger when used by an admin for developer will for Facebook to crawl the page and update the meta info. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Shawn you can check this website..http://www.santabanta.com/ they are not using any og in their code ....

Comment: i edited in my response Sharma., if you do not define the url, the object will not receive an ID.